# How to disable a lightbox from opening in Drupal using lightbox2 module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, lightbox2

I currently have a drop down navigation that opens a modal lightbox window.

I would like to not open the the window if there in an option with no URL selected which is the first default option.

I have tried a number of techniques such as:
- returning false on the onsubmit event of the form. 
- Attempting to bind a click event to the goURL a href link using jQuery that would then either
1) call event.preventDefault or 2)stop propagation events.
- coding an onclick event to the goURL a href link.

Below is the html code

```
<h3>Request a <span>Quote</span></h3>
<form action="#">
    <div class="select">
        <select id="URL" name="URL" onchange="$('#goLink').attr('href', $('#URL').val());">
            <option value="">- Choose a Link -</option>
            <option value="/node/1/lightbox2">Link 1</option>
            <option value="/node/2/lightbox2">Link 2</option>
            <option value="/node/3/lightbox2">Link 3</option>
            <option value="/node/4/lightbox2">Link 4</option>
            <option class="last" value="/node/5/lightbox2">Link 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
<a href="#" id="goLink" class="go" rel="lightframe">GO</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the **rel** attribute if you need a simple link without lightbox effect. The href attribute does not affect it.

Here is a sample of a jQuery code (not necessary the perfect one but just as an example):

```
$("#url").change(function(){
    var selected = $('url :selected'), // Get the selected option
        selectedVal = selected.val(); // Get the selected option value

    if (selectedValue == "") {
        $('#goLink').removeAttr('rel'); // Remove the rel if the value is empty
    } else {
        $("#goLink").attr('href',selectedVal).attr('rel','lightframe'); // Add rel=lightframe attribute and the href
    }
});
```